# Piwik Web Analytics - Anyone with experience of it?

Tags: open-source, analytics, evaluation

I'm considering trying to get more granular analytics for my sites than the free plan on my current provider, [Clicky](http://getclicky.com), provides.

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) looks like a strong contender in the analytics space (and I'm surprised I haven't heard about it before) but I want to be sure I'm not throwing the baby out with the bathwater by swapping to it.

Does anyone have any experience with this software and - in particular - are there any people out there who've tried customising the code or developing their own plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to ghommey's response: we're also using Piwik right now and it fits the bill for our purposes. Separating IP ranges isn't really a concern for us as we use separate development and deployment servers.

As for customizing it, I've written a couple of Piwik plugins, one of which served to enable SSO for our (non-PHP) project. Writing the code itself has been relatively straightforward; however their authentication cookies violate the HTTP cookie RFCs (RFC2109 and RFC2068) in that they use illegal characters so there might be also other dragons in places.

Answer (score 2):

AS of the latest release (q1 2010) filtering IPs is possible.

Comment: Yeah, noticed there are a lot of compelling changes on the boil for this version and the upcoming 0.7 release (probably) looks like they'll have some excellent (and much-needed) UI updates that'll make this my stats package of choice.